# MVC: deny simultaneously data-edit

Tags: javascript, php

this is a rather common question.

i am creating a page where users have to login and can create/edit datasets.

it must be possible to deny simultaneously editing of such a dataset.
should i do that with sessions? are sessions reliable enough?
the method should be as forgiving as possible to the user (closing browser window, timeouts)
but needs some restrictions, too.

what would be the best approach here?

i use a self developed url-driven mvc which uses sql, js, php (&smarty).

thanks in advance

Comment: You want a locking strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Memcache. You can put server's memory if the data-set id is locked. Whenever you try to edit, you read the data-set id from memory